# How to edit magento 2 grouped products page?

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

How do I edit and change Magento 2 grouped products page? I wish to be able to add more table cells on the page so I can add more information that I need to show from each product in the grouped products. Unfortunately, it seems I'm missing something very important to be able to do this.

Here's what iv done so far:

Copied the

`magento/module_grouped_product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml`

and created a new folder in

`theme/Magento_Grouped_Product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type`

Iv also included the `view/type/default.phtml` and `layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml` in my theme.

After copying these files I tested the grouped.phtml and added a new `<th>` with just a text `TEST` and ran `setup:upgrade` and `setup:static-content:deploy`, to ensure the updates would get loaded, but nothing has changed. Have I copied the wrong file(s) to my theme or done the whole process wrong?

Comment: check my answer it will help you, we do not need to create `view/frontend` folder in our theme.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create folder like, **Magento_GroupedProduct** inside the theme,

**app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml**

Now clear cache and check your changes.

Comment: So its not Magento_Grouped_Product, but Magento_GroupedProduct? Also a second question, do I make the changes to default.phtml and not in the grouped.phtm, because grouped.phtml seems to have the actual content I would want to change compared to default.html which only has the quantity messages.

Comment: You can change any files related to your changes based on your requirement. Yes Module name must be Magento_GroupedProduct

Comment: Made the changes, but still no change on the page itself. Any idea what could be causing this issue? I also used the setup:upgrade and setup:static-content:deploy to ensure it's not because of them that it isnt working.

Comment: i have updated my code. please remove view/frontend folder from previous path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create new folders in your theme with `Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/`.

Paste PHTML file like `grouped.phtml`.

After that you need to run only `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: Tried it but no help either. Could it be that the problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: have you selected your theme from admin?

Comment: Yes the theme is already in place and working as it should mostly. Its just that as explained earlier I need to change the grouped products layout so I may bring more data from the product to the frontpage and for that I need more table cells to build it.

Comment: Is there any module for that? Actually, I have tried same with my sample Magento 2 and it is working for me.

Comment: Didn't find any extra modules and I tried the changes but no help. Any other ideas what could be causing this?

Ps. Does it affect the changes in anyway that this is a multistore? This theme is only in use with the store number 2 I'm trying to change.

Comment: There are causes. 
1) Maybe another module has override core phtml.
2) Maybe that theme does not assign to the right store.

Comment: Do you get the solution?

Comment: No solution for now. I will search for other methods to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

**Override below file in your theme :**

> /vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

**In your theme :**

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

**Replace below table code :**

```
<table class="table data grouped" id="super-product-table">
    <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Grouped product items') ?></caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col item" scope="col" style="width: 30%;"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Test') ?></th> 
        <th class="col item" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Product Name') ?></th>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></th>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Test Content')) ?>" class="col item"  style="width: 30%;">
                Test Content
            </td>
            <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col item">
                <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                 <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" class="col qty">
            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                <div class="control qty">
                    <input type="number"
                           name="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                           data-selector="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                           value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getQty() * 1 ?>"
                           title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                           class="input-text qty"
                           data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                           data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>
                </div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
            && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
            && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                $_item,
                \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
            ))): ?>
            <tr class="row-tier-price">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                        $_item,
                        \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                    ) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="unavailable"
                colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('No options of this product are available.') ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php endif; ?>
</table>
```

I have added one cell in table please review attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: @J.Douh is that working for you ?